# "Who is this for?" vs "Who does this belong to?"

Tags: american-english, speech

Yesterday I asked an Australian friend "Who is this for?" in reference to a wallet on his desk. He laughed and thought my sentence didn't make sense in the context of the situation. Instead, he proposed that I should have asked "Who does this belong to?"

Can someone help me understand the difference and whether my usage was correct or incorrect, or whether my friend's response to my query was warranted (at least conversationally)?

Answer (score 4):

If I were the Australian friend, I guess I'd have misunderstood the question too at first.

*"Who is this for?"* could imply the wallet was perhaps a present **prepared for somebody**. Almost like your friend put it there to be taken by somebody else. So he chuckled when he heard what you said. After all, there's was probably money and credit cards there!

*Who does this belong to?* is a good suggestion, now you're asking **who the owner of the wallet is**.

But I would prefer a simple

> Whose wallet is it?

Comment: How doesn't "Who does this belong to?" have implications that it is a present for someone? Any argument applied to "Who is this for?" can be used similarly for "Who does this belong to?"

Comment: A present *prepared* for someone does not yet *belong* to that someone.

Comment: If I ask Santa Clause "Who does this present belong to?" in reference to any particularly present, then he should respond that it belongs to himself?

Comment: I guess he'd say, "Technically, Jane, this present does not yet belong to anybody. But it's for Mike, in case you must know" :)

Comment: So a presented prepared for someone belongs to whom?

Comment: Depends on the definition. If you define *belong* as *to have in one's possession*, then little Mikey will have to wait before his present arrives.

Comment: The *whose* version is the normal one, although I agree that *who is this for* has a different connotation.